# Instruction encoding for atomic increment of a long variable

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86-64, atomic, inline-assembly

I need to get instruction encoding for atomic increment of a long variable. I was thinking of writing some inline gcc assembly and use the gdb disassembled output to get the answer. Here is what I did.

```
#include <stdint.h>

int lock_inc(uint64_t *value) {

  __asm__ __volatile__
  (
   "lock inc %0;\n"
   :
   : "r"(value)
   : "memory"
  );
}

uint64_t value = 0;

int main() {

  lock_inc(&value);

}
```

But when I try to compile it I get the following error.

> lockinc.c: Assembler messages: lockinc.c:5: Error: expecting lockable
>   instruction after `lock'

What am I doing wrong? By the way if somebody know the direct answer (encoding) that would be great as well. (I was referring to some sites for getting it directly but wasn't sure of the answer. Felt letting gcc do it would be easier.)

Comment: What does your instruction manual say? I don't suppose you would be undertaking such work without having the manual open and ready for consultation at all times.

Comment: Sound suggestion. :). Guess I was trying to find the easy way out.

Comment: A "how to do it" question that does not require asm: stackoverflow.com/questions/2353371/how-to-do-an-atomic-increment-and-fetch-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use lock on registers.  You must use "m" for the constraint, not "r".  Also, since you are both reading and writing, "value" should be an output marked with "+".  And why not just use __sync_add_and_fetch?

Comment: Got it working with your suggestions. Thanks. I cannot use __sync_add_and_fetch because this code needs to be generated at runtime and then executed. By the way answer is "f0 48 ff 05 0a 04 20 00" which translates to "lock incq 0x20040a(%rip)" in my case where f0 is LOCK prefix, 48 is REX prefix and ff is opcode for incq.

Comment: @chamibuddhika Embedding magic constants like `0x20040a` in code samples / answers is ... very rarely the actual (correct) answer. In particular if you're talking about _generated code_. Depending where in memory that block of code lives, that "magic" will change. Better stuff that genie back into the bottle ;-)

Comment: True :). But my requirement was to get encoding of the instruction itself with lock and required prefixes ignoring the '0x20040a' part which is just the operand portion of the instruction which will change anyway.